# Pretrain RoBERTa model with new data using PyTorch library

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, pretraining

I've pretrained the RoBERTa model with new data using a '**simpletransformers**' library:

```
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel

OUTPUT_DIR = 'roberta_output/'
model = ClassificationModel('roberta', 'roberta-base',use_cuda=False, num_labels=22,
                        args={'overwrite_output_dir':True, 'output_dir':OUTPUT_DIR})

model.train_model(train_df)

result, model_outputs, wrong_predictions = model.eval_model(test_df) # model evaluation on test data
```

where '**train_df**' is a pandas dataframe that consists of many samples (=rows) with two columns: the 1st column is a text data - input; the 2nd column is a category (=label) - output.

I need to create the same model and pretrain it as above but using '**PyTorch**' library instead of '**Simpletransformers**' library. Is there any way to make it simple as the code above?

I've loaded the pretrained model as it was said [here](https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_fairseq_roberta/):

```
import torch
roberta = torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'roberta.large', pretrained=True)
roberta.eval()  # disable dropout (or leave in train mode to finetune)
```

I also changed the number of labels to predict in the last layer:

```
roberta.register_classification_head('new_task', num_classes=22)
```

But, I can't find how I can pretrain the classifier with my 'train_df'.
The only way I've found so far is from [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/blob/main/examples/roberta/README.pretraining.md) where we use a PyTorch toolkit '**fairseq**' and fairseq cli to pretrain RoBERTa model. Is this the only option or can it be done more simply?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been struggling with this type of problem. I followed and modified [this](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/aditya-malte/2d4f896f471be9c38eb4d723a710768b/smallberta_pretraining.ipynb#scrollTo=HOG-fl1cGhJ4) tutorial from HuggingFace (which is deprecated by now because it uses an older version of transformers). The final result is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18hHnxmzRRROmg7p-ykrqsgksZje403og?usp=sharing). Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/82857)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not pre-training the model. You are fine-tuning on your data. Second of all, you can follow the https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training It has great way of showing how you can use either `pytorch` or `tensorflow` framework to fine-tune your model.